# how to keep the data into temporary table?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

```
Select TOP 1  @TaxId= REFQualifierValue
                From  OPENXML (@XmlHandleTemp,'NewDataSet/CMSQualifier',2)        
                with (
                     [identityColumn] [varchar] (10) ,FileClaimNo  int ,EntityIDCode Varchar(20),EntityTypeQualifier  Varchar(20),PreviousEntityTypeQualifier varchar(10),Qualifier varchar(2),LineItemNo int ,REFQualifier Varchar(20),REFQualifierValue varchar(50)
                    )CmsQualifier
               where CmsQualifier.FileClaimNo=@FileClaimNo
```

The above query is repeting so many times in a procedure. so to avoid it i would like to keep these information in temp table or table variable.
kindly can any one tell me how can i do it.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Declare the structure of temporary table variable as per your requirement , below is the example with two columns in temporary table :

```
declare @tableVariable Table([index] integer,TaxId varchar(50)) 
declare  @TaxId as varchar(50);
```

set the value in variable @TaxId like

```
 Select TOP 1 @TaxId=[column_name] from [table_name]
```

you can now insert your value to temporary table with integer type index

```
insert into @tableVariable([index],  TaxId) values (1, @TaxId)
```

Comment: Dear Isac_Pro  my table is like below then how can i rewrite the above query CREATE TBALE #temp_Tune (
[identityColumn] [varchar] (10) ,FileClaimNo  int ,EntityIDCode Varchar(20),EntityTypeQualifier  Varchar(20),PreviousEntityTypeQualifier varchar(10),Qualifier varchar(2),LineItemNo int ,REFQualifier Varchar(20),REFQualifierValue varchar(50)
)

Comment: No , its not about on how your table structure but its about what and how many values are you going to retrieve from your table for saving into temporary table. as from your question i found that you want to retrieve   taxid only,so i gave you example of 2 columns one for temp table primary key and one for your retrieved value ok!

Comment: i can pass but can not reply now , because now i am in my office and mail checking are not allowed here. My email id is isachin100@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
insert into #temp_Tune ([identityColumn],FileClaimNo   ,EntityIDCode ,EntityTypeQualifier       ,PreviousEntityTypeQualifier ,
Qualifier ,LineItemNo  ,REFQualifier ,REFQualifierValue )
Select TOP 1  
[identityColumn],FileClaimNo   ,EntityIDCode ,EntityTypeQualifier    ,PreviousEntityTypeQualifier ,
Qualifier ,LineItemNo  ,REFQualifier ,REFQualifierValue 
            From  OPENXML (@XmlHandleTemp,'NewDataSet/CMSQualifier',2)        
            with (
                 [identityColumn] [varchar] (10) ,FileClaimNo  int ,EntityIDCode     Varchar(20),EntityTypeQualifier  Varchar(20),PreviousEntityTypeQualifier varchar(10),Qualifier    varchar(2),LineItemNo int ,REFQualifier Varchar(20),REFQualifierValue varchar(50)
                )CmsQualifier
            where CmsQualifier.FileClaimNo=@FileClaimNo
```

Comment: Hi rohini , i will not try your query i will try it now

Comment: @Franklin: You should accept answers if your problem gets resolved. This helps others looking for the same.